# BigQuery: Load data from Sheets - Access denied

Tags: upload, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I uploaded a table **from** **Spreadsheet** to BigQuery using the built-in UI.
It turns out that only people with access to the Gsheet can run queries using the new table.

Is there a way to define a general option to allow everyone to run queries on this new table?

Otherwise I need to run a `Select * from` and save a new table each time or think of sharing the spreadsheet with everyone in the company.

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between "share the table with everyone" VS. "share the spreadsheet with everyone with readonly permission"?

Answer (score 0):

You could share dataset with specific people.
Also what's the difference between "share the table with everyone" VS. "share the spreadsheet with everyone with readonly permission"?

Answer (score 0):

In a domain context you can have a document readable by everyone in your domain without them getting notified or seeing it popup in their Google Drive. I believe you just need to click on *Get shareable link* in the share dialog to do that.

I agree to Xuejian that there's little difference in sharing a dataset or a sharing a spreadsheet.